# Get records from database in interval of 2 seconds

Tags: mysql, database

I have a question about mysql:

```
$result = mysql_query("
  SELECT * FROM
     Table order by rand() limit 10
```

When I write the script 10 rows are fetched in 2-3 second.
Is it possible to fetch each 1 row with 2 second?

Comment: what do you mean by fetching each row? If you just want the first row, you can do so by changing the limit to 1

Comment: Please come up with a better title that covers your question (_"Mysql database expert needed"_ doesn't mean anything to us) and explain why/what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Am making a autolike site for facebook

Comment: @hpscool That's not legal -1

Comment: question title is like you're hiring :D

Comment: When i set to order by rand()limit 1 1 user like my status,  When i set the order by rand limit 10.10 user like my status in 2-3 second ..But i want 10 user like my status with 2 second interval

Comment: Updated the title to make it look more of like a question than a hiring process :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **No**(*atleast using plain MySQL*). When you write the select statement it will fetch the rows as soon as you execute it. You cannot retrieve it interval of 2 seconds.

As an alternative you can change the limit to 1 and execute your query in interval of 2 second but that would not be a very good approach.

Comment: Is there any other mysql query i have 15 rows in mysql database can i fetch 1 by 1 by 3 second interval???

Comment: @hpscool:- For what? As far as I know there is no such query which can do that, why you want the result in interval of 2 seconds?

Comment: Is there any other mysql query i have 15 rows in mysql database can i fetch 1 by 1 by 3 second interval???

Comment: Am making a autolike site for facebook

Comment: When i set to order by rand()limit 1 1 user like my status

Comment: When i set the order by rand limit 10 10 user like my status in 2-3 second

Comment: But i want 10 user like my status with 2 second interval

Comment: its **ponssible** in the programming language you are dealing with. may be PHP, JS, C# OR any other..

Comment: Its php can you help me plz